# General questions about Inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm creating a Journal System for doctors, where a doctor can go in and look at a patient and also look at the patients Xrays and the images belonging to that Xray.

- There can be more than one Patient.
- There can be more than one Xray for each patient.
- There can be more than one XrayImage for each Xray.

Here is the class layout:

[image]

http://i44.tinypic.com/w9w37d.png

The problem that I'm having is that it seems that I always end up asking Patient for information and not Patient.Xray or Patient.Xray.XrayImage. Is this correct?

For example:

Patient have a getPatient method which retrieves data from a Database and sets all the fields in Patient, so far so good.

Then I have, for example, three Xrays in the database belonging to this patient and I want to create 3 instances of Patient.Xray so I have a method called getXrayIDs in Patient. This retrieves all the XrayIDs belonging to that patient and stores the IDs in a list in Patient and these IDs are displayed in the UI in a dropdown box. When I change the ID in the dropdown box another method called Patient.getXray(int XrayID) is called and this creates a new instance of Xray and the information is displayed in the UI.

XrayImages works in pretty much the same except that Xray has a method called getXrayImageIDs.

The problem is that I want to work against a class object (Patient, Xray, XrayImage) but at the same time I don't want to retrieve more data than necessary from the database so is this a good approach?

It feels like I'm not programming in proper OOP and I should ignore how much data I retrieve from the database, program in proper OOP and later on fix the database performance.

So instead I should program like this:

```
 Patient patient = new Patient()
 patient.getXrays() // This one should create a new Xray instance
                 // and Patient should have references to these instances.
 patient.xray[i].getXrayImages // This one should create a new XrayImage 
        //instance and Xray should have references to these instances.
```

Another thought: When the dropdown box value is being changed (as in this case) it should retrieve the data from the Xray and XrayImage class and not from the database. Should I just try to load the data from the database into the Xray and XrayImage class one time and then the user will have information and will work aginst the object instead of retrieving the information each time the XrayID is changed?

Comment: "when the dropdown box value is being changed ... it should retrieve the data from ... class and not from the database" is jumping levels of architecture - dangerous approach when you are trying to design an application (which is what this potentially off-topic question seem to be about).

Comment: I would go with your last thought. Instead of doing 4 trips to the database, I would do just one trip and bring everything related to that patient.

Comment: One more note: your title makes no connection with body of the post as there is absolutely no inheritance in the body of the question.

Comment: No inheritance in sight here. And no need for it.

Comment: And do not optimize to soon. Get it working properly first, you won't be fetching thousands of patients per minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are talking about is about a loading strategy. Basically we have to distinguish [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) and eager loading here (names for these strategies can differ in different sources). Lazy loading, as the name implies, only loads a value from the database when it is actually used. In contrary, eager loading already loads as much data as possible or possibly necessary from the database as soon as any root object is requested from the database.

This has nothing to do with the object oriented design or inheritance. You can design your objects one way and without changing them, use the one or the other loading strategy.

Which loading strategy you choose depends on your application and the use cases usually faced. There is no generally right or better one of them.

For example eager loading usually causes the user to wait longer at the beginning of a new page load, but then when he clicks something on this page, the response is there immediately. It's the opposite with lazy loading: With this, the page load at the beginning is fast, but for all the tiny reloads while using the page, a new database access has to be performed and therefor there is always a tiny waiting time for the user for each of his actions on the page. You have to decide, as a developer, which approach probably feels more convenient for the user. You might also try out both approaches and have users test your application and give you feedback about which one of the applications made them feel more comfortable.

In some cases, constraints can force you into one or the other strategy. For example when you are dealing with large hierarchies of objects in your database, the eager loading strategy can cause a very long loading time. I've seen loading times of more than 1 minute in real world applications. And you will most likely not need all the fetched information. In such a case, it is necessary to use lazy loading.

Comment: Perfect answer. I thought it had something to do with OOP but what I was actually looking for was if I want "eager loading" or "lazy loading". For the moment I will go with "eager loading" as I don't have that much data in the database and therefore the "eager loading time" will still be pretty fast. Thanks again for a perfect answer!